# Ubuntu Nginx - changing the server root directory

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I really depends on changing the server root directory from `/var/www` to the `/srv/http`.

Because if I sue:

```
server {

    server_name www.domain.tld;
    root /srv/http/project/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
       # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
       # current version of your application, you should pass the real
       # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
       # FPM.
       # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
       # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
       # for more information).
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
       # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
       # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
       # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
       internal;
   }

   # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
   # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
   location ~ \.php$ {
     return 404;
   }

   error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
   }
```

does not work.

The system is Ubuntu 16.04 and server Nginx.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your root directory is `/srv/http/project/web` but not `/var/www`, and in order to change it to `/srv/http`, you got to find `root /srv/http/project/web;` in above configuration(which is third line of the same) and change it to `root /srv/http;`. -Thank You :)

Comment: Hi.
So this is a link to the public directory of the project.
For example, if the project is in directory `/var/www` and how to put an `root /var/www/project/web` it all works
the point is that the server does not go to the folder `/srv/http`
- Thank You

Comment: Seriously, i can't understand what do you mean by above, and i don't see any link,

Comment: Because I have all my projects in the folder `/srv/http/` (`/srv` - a separate disk partition) and the previous system (Arch) me everything worked as it should.
For reasons independent from me I had to change to Ubuntu. In Ubuntu server link to another directory. This is the whole issue that I can not compel him to instead of `/var/www` used the `/srv/http`.

Comment: Bro, Why don't you change the root value as mentioned above?

Comment: Because the product has `index.php` in this directory, and this is the root directory for the project.